# My Raspbian doesn't reboot via a Python application

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, reboot

I am desperately trying to find out a way to force my Raspberry Pi running Raspbian to restart when a certain condition is met (Python script), however I got no success so far...

I have tried the following statements by using popen:

```
sudo reboot -i -p
sudo reboot -f
sudo shutdown -r -f now
```

I thought the problem could be calling it through the Python application itself, therefore I wrote a small C program to kill all running Python application and then reboot, but no success...

My Raspberry is enough powered (Red LED is always on) and all commands I described above work fine when called directly from the command window.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,

EDITED:
Adding my python script as required:

```
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

    def reboot():
        echo.echo("Rebooting...")
        db.write_alarm(get_alarm_status())
        upload.upload_log()
        reboot_statement = "sudo shutdown -r -f now"
        popen_args = reboot_statement.split(" ")
        Popen(popen_args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

Comment: Can you paste your python script?

Comment: Hi Anupam. Just added. Thx

Comment: I think you may have to run your script as root and get rid of the `sudo`. Not from your user account.

Comment: @Geotob, `sudo` will work fine without a password if it's set up correctly

Comment: @JohnLaRooy-AKAgnibbler yea true *if* set up correctly:) Thus just a comment.

Comment: Hi Geotob. Other statements work fine with sudo e.g.: mpg321. I don't think this is the issue. Thanks anyway

Comment: You didn't describe the problem. Does the program raise an error? (Which one?) Does it output something? Does your computer crash?

Comment: How are you calling the script try running the python script as sudo - sudo reboot.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

create a file called reboot.py with the following contents:

```
import os
os.system("shutdown -r now")
```

then call it like this:

```
sudo python reboot.py
```

Assuming this works you can probably invoke your original script with sudo to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `shell=True` id you want the shell to process the arguments

```
Popen("sudo shutdown -r -f now", stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
```

Comment: I broke the arguments as suggest (see in my question) but still no success. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Try `Popen("sudo shutdown -r -f now", shell=True)` in the REPL. What does it say?

Comment: Hi John. Exactly the same. :-(

Comment: I guess it doesn't have to do with the call itself, for instance other applications called just like that work just fine. I guess something might be blocking the reboot.